# Surfaces of general type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

What methods do we know about proving-disproving existence of rational points on surfaces of general type?
I was recently asked. My gut answer was- 'nothing'.

Comment: I would agree with your sentiment

Comment: Yes. The task of detecting Zariski-density of rational points on varieties of general type over $\mathbf{Q}$ is widely open. I think a major step forward would be addressing the Lang-Bombieri conj even just in the special case of surfaces. My feeling is that so far no one has any idea on where to even start, and it's regarded as being harder than Faltings' finiteness thm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually nothing, as you guessed $-$ though you might get lucky:

i) There might be a local obstruction (e.g. no rational points on the
twisted Fermat sextic surfaces $x^6+y^6+z^6+t^6=0$ and $x^6+2y^6+4z^6=8t^6$).

ii) the surface, say $S$, may map to a curve with finitely many rational points.

iii) $S$ may be contained in an abelian variety, in which case Faltings II 
applies (the big example is symmetric squares of non-hyperelliptic curves).

[it's been noted that both (ii) and (iii) mean that $S$ has nontrivial 
Albanese variety.]

iv) finally $S$ may have nontrivial $\pi_1$, in which case one can lift to 
unramified covers and try to apply (ii) or (iii).  For example, if 
$C$ and $C'$ are curves of genus at least $2$ with involutions $\iota,\iota'$ 
at least one of which has no fixed points then we can prove 
$(C \times C') \, / \, (\iota,\iota')$ has finitely many rational points 
by applying (ii) or (iii) to finitely many twists of $C \times C'$.

In each of cases (ii), (iii), (iv), some further luck may be needed to 
find all rational points and prove that the list is complete.

Comment: Even when there are local points everywhere, there may be nonzero global obstructions, such as the Brauer-Manin obstruction.

Comment: True.  So I should (with acknowledgement to you) add this as (v), or perhaps (i').
Do you have an example?  I suppose one could be concocted by
taking an arbitrary cover of an obstructed surface that's not
of general type, but one could also ask for a "genuinely"
general-type example, thought it might be tough to define
this notion precisely.  Are there any "global obstructions" known
in this setting other than Brauer-Manin?